# Exchange Server - New-MailboxExportRequest not exporting mailbox

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

A week back I  upgraded my `Exchange` environment from `E2K10 SP1` to `E2K10 SP3`.
Since then, I am unable to export mailboxes with `New`->`MailboxExportRequest` powershell script.  Even though, I'm having right permission to export the mailboxes.
The `cmdlet` which I'm making use of is this:
`New`-`MailboxExportRequest`-`Mailbox user`-`FilePath` `\\MailServer\PST\user.pst`

The above `cmdlet` is identified and it is has been queued permanently.

Can anyone tell me why this has happened?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a DAG?

Have you tried to restart the Exchange Mailbox Replication service on all CAS servers to verify the result?

I suggest you to check the status of this mailbox database if it is mounted. You can use the following command to check this.

Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Identity "mailbox database name"

Alongside, please make use of the Get-MoveRequestStatistics cmdlet to view full information about move requests.